# How to do sftp from node app on heroku with public key encryption?

Tags: node.js, encryption, heroku, ftp

I'm in a bit of unknown territory here.  I have a node app deployed on heroku and need to sftp a file from the app to a host using public key encryption.  Never done anything like this, so direction is much appreciated!

Using ursa (https://github.com/quartzjer/ursa) to generate the keys.

Thought about using node-ftp (https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp) to sftp the file.  But I'm not sure how to incorporate the key in the ftp.

Using QuotaGuard Static to create a static IP since the host needs to know the IP that the file is coming from.

Thoughts are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
sftp -i /path/to/private/keyfile user@remoteaddress
```